# Why is Google OAuth 2.0 asking for web app verification, when I have not added any scopes?

Tags: google-oauth

I'd like to publish a web app on Google that allows users to login via their Google account.

I haven't chosen any sensitive or restricted scopes - in fact, I haven't chosen any scopes at all:
[image]
From testing, I know my app is able to retrieve an email address, a name and a profile picture. I'm only interested in the email address and the name.

However, when I click Publish app, Google informs me that the way I have set-up the app requires verification, with what is quite an arduous set of tasks:

[image]

Can someone please help me understand if this is really required for my use case, or if there is some way to avoid this verification process?

Or maybe I've misunderstood, and this verification process is required.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution. Even without scopes, if you have included a custom logo in your consent screen setup, your app requires verification.

Remove the logo in the consent screen setup and your app is publishable without verification.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the confidence to go ahead and submit for verification - the only thing I have is a custom logo.

Comment: You have saved me an enormous headache, thank you